# Regex to extract first word in a url path

Tags: regex

I have this regex to extract the application name out of the url path

```
\/(?<app>[^\.\/]+)[\/\?]
```

/foo/bar  -> foo

/foo?bar=x  -> foo

However, this is not found

/foo

How can I improve the regex to include /foo without including app-less urls like

/?foo=bar

The last one should return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\/(?<app>[^?\/]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](http://%5E%5C/(?%3Capp%3E[%5E?%5C/%5Cn]*))

`^/` will make sure to match at starting `/` and `[^?\/]*` will find a match before a `?` or `/` is found next.